# how can i optimize my regular rectangle checker in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have 4 points and check if 3 of it have vertical and horizontal lines with other given points. It looks messy but i have no idea how to do it in right way.

```
line(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2)).
vertical(line(point(X, Y1), point(X, Y2))).
horizontal(line(point(X1, Y), point(X2, Y))).
rectangle(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2), point(X3, Y3), point(X4, Y4)).

regular(rectangle(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2), point(X3, Y3), point(X4, Y4))) :-
    vertical(line(point(X1, Y1), P1)),
    (P1 = point(X2, Y2);
    P1 = point(X3, Y3);
    P1 = point(X4, Y4)),
    horizontal(line(point(X1, Y1), P2)),
    (P2 = point(X2, Y2);
    P2 = point(X3, Y3);
    P2 = point(X4, Y4)),
    vertical(line(point(X2, Y2), P3)),
    (P3 = point(X1, Y1);
    P3 = point(X3, Y3);
    P3= point(X4, Y4)),
    horizontal(line(point(X2, Y2), P4)),
    (P4 = point(X1, Y1);
    P4 = point(X3, Y3);
    P4= point(X4, Y4)),
    vertical(line(point(X3, Y3), P5)),
    (P5 = point(X1, Y1);
    P5 = point(X2, Y2);
    P5 = point(X4, Y4)),
    horizontal(line(point(X3, Y3), P6)),
    (P6 = point(X1, Y1);
    P6 = point(X2, Y2);
    P6 = point(X4, Y4)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of singleton warnings: they hints your code needs rethinking, and you should check that vert/horiz lines are [not degenerate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%5C%3D)/2).

So, I would write it in this way:

```erlang
%line(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2)).
vertical(point(X, Y1), point(X, Y2)) :- Y1 =\= Y2.
horizontal(point(X1, Y), point(X2, Y)) :- X1 =\= X2.
%rectangle(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2), point(X3, Y3), point(X4, Y4)).

regular(rectangle(A,B,C,D)) :-
    (   vertical(A,B)
    ->  horizontal(B,C),
        vertical(C,D),
        horizontal(D,A)
    ;   horizontal(A,B),
        vertical(B,C),
        horizontal(C,D),
        vertical(D,A)
    ).
```

just to make easier to highlight the joins among corners, and reduce the alternatives that Prolog must evaluate to infer the regular/1 is satisfied.
So far, either the first segment is vertical, and then the following chain must be horizontal,vertical,horizontal, or horizontal, and then vertical,horizontal,vertical.
This is the kind of optimization that results from program structure simplification.

Depending on the purpose of your program, you should also decide which kind of arithmetic to use. That is, vertical/2 (and horizontal/2) could be made more general in the following way:

```erlang
vertical(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2)) :- X1 =:= X2, Y1 =\= Y2.
```

and then could accept some expression on the X coordinate, as it does for the Y coordinate.

If your geometry is restricted on an integer grid (for instance, you're developing a basic 2D UI layout system), you could opt instead for [library(clpfd)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) - if your system supports it. Then the constraints would use the specific clpfd operators:

```erlang
vertical(point(X1, Y1), point(X2, Y2)) :- X1 #= X2, Y1 #\= Y2.
```

If you go this way, then also remember that 'impure' constructs (like if-then-else, that is `->`) should be banned or at least carefully confined in a safe evaluation path. Then, regular/1 should become

```erlang
regular(rectangle(A,B,C,D)) :-
    vertical(A,B),
    horizontal(B,C),
    vertical(C,D),
    horizontal(D,A)
;   horizontal(A,B),
    vertical(B,C),
    horizontal(C,D),
    vertical(D,A)
.
```

This kind of declarative arithmetic enable - for instance - a query like this one

```erlang
?- Vs=[X1,X2,Y1,Y2],Vs ins 1..4,regular(rectangle(point(X1,Y1),point(X1,Y2),point(X2,Y2),point(X2,Y1))),findall(Ps,(label(Vs),Ps=Vs),All),length(All,N).
Vs = [X1, X2, Y1, Y2],
All = [[1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 1, 4], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2|...], [1, 2|...], [1|...], [...|...]|...],
N = 144,
X1 in 1..4,
X2#\=X1,
X1#\=X2,
X2 in 1..4,
Y1 in 1..4,
Y2#\=Y1,
Y1#\=Y2,
Y2 in 1..4 .
```

that shows how many regular rectangles are allowed in a grid of size 4.